# How to pass Python args from nodejs using Python-Shell package?

Tags: python, node.js

I'm using this [python-shell package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and very new to the world of python and nodejs.

I'm looking to pass values to a python script below.

**script.py**

```
my_name = [0]
print("Hello and welcome " + my_name + "!")
```

I would like to pass the arg of "Bruce Wayne" below and have the above script.py receive it in the **my_name** variable.

**pythonShell.js**

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

    var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python', 
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      // make sure you use an absolute path for scriptPath
      scriptPath: '/home/username/Test_Project/Python_Script_dir',
      args: ['Bruce Wayne']
    };

    PythonShell.run('script.py', options, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
      console.log('results: %j', results);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple methods for accessing [command line arguments](https://stackabuse.com/command-line-arguments-in-python/).

Here's an example using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) (which contains the arguments).

Also, a loop of the `sys.argv` is included (notice that the script with path is the first arg).

script.py

```py
import sys

my_name = sys.argv[1]

for n, a in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print('arg {} has value {} endOfArg'.format(n, a))
print("Hello and welcome " + str(my_name) + "!")
```

JavaScript

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '/path/to/python/bin/python3.7',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: '/absolute/path/to/script/',
    args: ['Bruce Wayne']
};

PythonShell.run('numSO1.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

Output (reformatted since the array is all one line):

```
results: [
    "arg 0 has value /path/to/script/script.py endOfArg",
    "arg 1 has value Bruce Wayne endOfArg",
    "Hello and welcome Bruce Wayne!"]
```